# Error 'java.lang.NullPointerException' performing JNDI operation 'list' on object name (AMQ4405)

Tags: websphere, jndi, ibm-mq

I am getting following error when i am trying to add another JNDI context factory than default IBM Web Context factory..

I am using the local default musr_mqadmin user with administrative rights on the server.

```
An unexpected error occurred connecting to the JNDI service provider.
The following message contains text from the JNDI service provider which might not be translated.
Error 'java.lang.NullPointerException' performing JNDI operation 'list' on object name ''. (AMQ4405)
  An unexpected error occurred connecting to the JNDI service provider.
  The following message contains text from the JNDI service provider which might not be translated.
  Error 'java.lang.NullPointerException' performing JNDI operation 'list' on object name ''. (AMQ4405)
  Severity: 30 (Severe Error)
  Explanation: An unexpected JNDI error prevented the operation from completing.
  Response: Check for FFSTs to determine the reason for the error. If symptoms persist, contact your Systems Administrator.
  If the error NullPointerException occurs when creating an object on a file system ensure that the user has the correct permissions to access the drive being used.
```

Answer (score 1):

A `NullPointerException` is **always** a bug. I suggest you open a support ticket with the software vendor so they can fix it for you.